# MvvmCross MvxHttpImageView error

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to bind a web image in a listview on Android, using Xamarin.Android and mvvmcross.  I'm getting this error though.

MvxBind:Error:  7.13 View type not found - Mvx.MvxHttpImageView
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Mvx.MvxHttpImageView

This is my axml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mynamespace.android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Mvx.MvxHttpImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/iconeView"
                    local:MvxBind="{'HttpImageUrl':{'Path':'imageUrl'}}" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            local:MvxBind="Text name" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            local:MvxBind="Text tagline" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using v3, then try

- `MvxImageView` instead of `MvxHttpImageView`
- `ImageUrl` instead of `HttpImageUrl`

The bound views are in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views

I think MvxImageView is also discussed in: http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/n2-lists-and-kittens-n1-days-of.html

You also need to include the MvvmCross File and DownloadCache Plugins, or else you'll get this error

> "No IMvxImageHelper registered - you must provide an image helper before you can use a MvxImageView"

Comment: also the old json syntax is disabled by default in v3 - so this syntax won't work local:MvxBind="{'HttpImageUrl':{'Path':'imageUrl'}}"